# .NET Regexp try to get all possible range of symbols

Tags: .net, regex

My regexp is

```
((?<=(^)|([^\\](\\\\)*))(y{1,4}))
```

it selects `y` symbol if its not backslashed or backslashed even number of times ( `y` or `\\y` `\\\\y` will select `y`, `\y` `\\\y` will not select anything ).

But I need to do same with `y` sequence, e.g.:

- `\yyyy` will not select anything (currently it selects `yyy`)
- `\\yyy` will select `yyy` (currently works properly)

How I can modify my regexp to accomplish this task ?
PS. I have used http://regexhero.net/tester/ for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anchor and I think your regex can be simplified a little:

```
^(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(y{1,4})
```